# How to delay start of countdown?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a way to set a delay before the countdown timer starts. Display the first loaded message for a period of time then start countdown.
I want to use only javascript, no jquery.
I have tried the setTimeout method but couldn't get it working whithin this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

html{background-color: #444}
body{color: cyan;}
img{width: 100%; max-width: 256px; height: auto;}
#example3div{border: 1px solid; padding: 10px; border-radius: 50%; font-size:     22px; width: 80%; text-align: center;  margin: auto;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var containerID = "example3div";
var number = 6;
var timerID = setInterval("CountdownTimer()",1000);

function CountdownTimer() {     
    if(number > 1){
    number--;
    ReplaceContentInContainer(containerID,number);
    }
    else
    {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    ReplaceContentInContainer(containerID,'<img alt="GREATHOMES.US"     src="http://greathomes.us/images/html5.png" /><p>Hello. I love learning how to     code! (-_-)</p>');
}
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.innerHTML = content;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="example3div">Get ready for the countdown of your life!!!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just var timerID = setInterval(CountdownTimer(),1000); instead of  var timerID = setInterval("CountdownTimer()",1000);

Comment: I had to leave the double quotes in there for it to work... http://greathomes.us/countdown/index.html MY BAD!! I DID NOT HAVE TO LEAVE THE DOUBLE QUOTES IN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your actual code, it looks like you want

```
var timerID = setInterval("CountdownTimer()",1000);
```

to become

```
var timerID;
setTimeout(function(){
    timerID = setInterval("CountdownTimer()",1000)
}, n);  // Where n is the number of milliseconds to wait
```

Comment: This one worked! :) http://greathomes.us/countdown/index.html  Thanks very much!!

Comment: Just so you know, using a string with setTimeout is a possible XSS vector.

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeout`'s are pretty easy to deal with, being virtually identical in operation with your already existing `setInterval`, here's an example:

```
setTimeout(CountdownTimer,2000);//call this after 2000ms

function CountdownTimer(){
   //your countdown timer code
}
```

Keep in mind that `setInterval` delays the first execution of it's contents - equal to it's specified interval - it doesn't fire immediately after calling it

---

You also have a typo there as @Deb says - it's:

```
var timerID = setInterval(CountdownTimer,1000); //functions calls are not specified in string format
```

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is :

Just change in your code from

```
var timerID = setInterval("CountdownTimer()",1000);
```

to

```
var timerID = setInterval(CountdownTimer,1000);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have the `()` at all

Comment: The JavaScript compiler will actually `eval` the string. The quotes around `CountdownTimer()` are actually fine

Comment: They're not really fine since using a string with `setTimeout` is a possible XSS vector.